# Setting text alignment with visio stencil

Tags: powershell, visio, stencils, shapesheet

I'm in the proccess of creating an automated visio diagram script in powershell, adding elements with text like so.

```
    $GROUP = $CPage.Drop($Stencil_AgentList, $x, $Y)
    $GROUP.Text = $MatchedGroup.Name
    $GROUP.AutoConnect($QUEUE, 0, $Stencil_Connector)
```

most of the functionality in terms of layout works at the moment, but i'm having serious troubles with the aspects that actually make diagrams look good.

I think this image explains it best: when you 'Edit Text' on an object, it appears to be aligned to the object in some way, either below or on top of it.

what I would like is to be able to align text, from the object itself, to the right side like below, where 'Example user name' is the ideal output.

[image]

I'm assuming this involves shapesheets etc. which I have almost no experience with.

Any help or resources on modifying these stencils so the 'text' area is where I want it to be would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this page : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa200988(v=office.10).aspx
The Text Block of a shape is by default, the same size as the enclosing rectangle of the shape. However, you can modify its size, position, rotation and the horizontal and vertical text alignment